# Почему я не попадаю в метод paintComponent()?

Tags: java, swing

Пытаюсь написать программу, которая будет выводить в окно картинку.

Окно создаётся, но метод `painComponent()` (который я перезаписываю) не вызывается.

Я выполняю метод `repaint` и надеюсь, что он вызовет метод `paintComponent()` (который я перезаписал)

Но этого не происходит.Подскажите, что я делаю не так?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class GameField extends JPanel {
    private Image imageBackground;

    GameField() {
        JPanel myPanel = new JPanel();
        JFrame myFrame = new JFrame();
        myFrame.setSize(576, 720);
        myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        myFrame.setContentPane(myPanel);
        loadImages();
        repaint();
        myFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void loadImages() {
        ImageIcon iiBackground = new ImageIcon("Pole1.png");
        imageBackground = iiBackground.getImage();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        System.out.println("Я сюда попал!");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GameField window = new GameField();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Разобрался. Оказывается вместо строчки:

```
myFrame.setContentPane(myPanel);
```

нужно было написать:

```
myFrame.setContentPane(this);
```

Я думал, что эти строки равноценны!?

Comment: При myFrame.setContentPane(myPanel); вы устанавливаете в фрейм обычную панель, без переопределенного метода paintComponent()
А при аргументе this вы указываете создающийся экземпляр объекта GameField который как раз имеет переопределенный вами метод.